# linux use watch command with multiple calls

Tags: linux, bash, shell, watch

How can I combine two (or more) calls by the `watch` command?
Such that they are run together (serially) and `watch` shows their combined output?

I.e. `watch command1 command2`

So to show the contents of two different directories:

```
watch $(ls dir1) $(ls dir2)
```

(The subshell parens were just added for clarity.)

Of course I could create a script to run both commands, pipe the results into a tempfile and cat it for its contents periodically through watch, but I'd refrain from it if this is natively possible somehow. :)

Subshells, grouping, process substitution did not help me, so I am out of luck and have no idea where to look now.

Is this possible at all?

UPDATE:

```
watch cat <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

gives me on the first iteration what I'd love to see refreshed periodically, but not repeatedly. :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`watch` by default runs the passed command in shell so you can pass it any command valid for shell:

```
watch 'ls dir1; ls dir2'
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I achieved the same with &&:

`watch 'ls dir1 && ls dir2'`

Comment: yes, except that ";" is not the same as "&&" in bash. ";" just sequences command in order no matter what happend when "&&" triggers the next command only if the previous was successful

Comment: How can `watch` be used with commands that involve process substitution? (E.g., `echo a | tee >(sed "s/a/b/")`). Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262534/watch-with-process-subtitution).