# Watch with Process Substitution

Tags: bash, unix, watch, process-substitution

I often run the command

```
squeue -u $USER | tee >(wc -l)
```

where `squeue` is a [Slurm command](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) to see how many jobs you are running. This gives me both the output from `squeue` and automatically tells how many lines are in it.

How can I `watch` this command?

`watch -n.1 "squeue -u $USER | tee >(wc -l)"` results in

```
Every 0.1s: squeue -u randoms | tee >(wc -l)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Wed May  9 14:46:36 2018

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `squeue -u randoms | tee >(wc -l)'
```

Comment: BTW, `watch` is crazy inefficient. Generally speaking, you'd be a lot better off implementing this function as a shell script with a loop in it. Even better if `slurm` has a non-polling interface (or even a log file that gets written to when jobs are added, cancelled or completed -- if you can avoid forking off a subshell and running a copy of the external `squeue` executable to poll a new value because the log hasn't been written to, that's a big win).

Comment: ...reading the fine docs, it looks like Slurm has built-in notification support, albeit with 15-second latency. If the tool's authors decided that that delay was appropriate, they're typically the people who would best know the factors that go into setting an appropriate polling rate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy interesting! thank you thank you for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `watch` man page:

> Note that command is given to "sh -c" which means that you may need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect.

`sh -c` also does not support process substitution, the syntax you're using here as `>()`.

---

Fortunately, that syntax isn't actually needed for what you're doing:

```
watch -n.1 'out=$(squeue -u "$USER"); echo "$out"; { echo "$out" | wc -l; }'
```

...or, if you **really** want to use your original code even at a heavy performance penalty (starting not just one but *two* new shells every tenth of a second -- first `sh`, and then `bash`):

```
bash_cmd() { squeue -u "$USER" | tee >(wc -l); } # create a function
export -f bash_cmd            # export function to the environment
watch -n.1 'bash -c bash_cmd' # call function from bash started from sh started by watch
```